# XMLRPC IP.Board could not locate an API module called

Tags: java, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I have a case: make work with forum by API fo Forum Engine IP.Board.

So i wrote next code:

```
package ru.test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

public class mainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        try {
            config.setServerURL(new URL("http://hbf.by/interface/board/index.php"));
            XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
            client.setConfig(config);
            Object[] params = new Object[]{"74600b7376c4b1db69eaf8f155f2d157", "ipb","','"};

            Object result = client.execute("fetchOnlineUsers", params);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

But i get exception

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: IP.Board could not locate an API module called ''
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
    at ru.test.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:23)
```

What's wrong?

In Documentation (http://community.invisionpower.com/resources/documentation/index.html/_/developer-resources/miscellaneous-articles/xml-rpc-api-r246) sayed:

> You should submit XML-RPC calls to the interface/board/index.php file.
>   You should send all parameters as a struct.
>
> Every request must submit two parameters: api_key - this should be
>   the key set up earlier. api_module - this should be "ipb".
>   Theoretically, you can create other modules, but "ipb" is all that
>   ships with IP.Board.

Where i make mistake.

And also how i can get methods.php file?

I write URL http://hbf.by/interface/board/modules/ipb/methods.php

But get blank page.

But also in Documentation sayed:

> Open the interface/board/modules/ipb/methods.php file to see which
>   parameters each method expects to receive and will send back in
>   response

May be some server need configurations, but in internet i can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does seem to match the documentation.

But, XMLRPC often specifies the module in the call like this

`Object result = client.execute("ipb.fetchOnlineUsers", params);`

You could try that.

Comment: No, it's doesn't  helps me.
I try
Object result = client.execute("ipb.fetchOnlineUsers", params);
and Object result = client.execute("API_Server.fetchOnlineUsers", params);

Comment: Also i create file php and try next: 1. I change url to my php file. 2. in file i make write all POST and GET data from request to Text file. But it's EMPTY! Why? Does client send data to server?

Answer (score 0):

I found where is trouble

don't use Object[] params = new Object[]{"74600b5f2d157", "ipb","','"};

instead use

HashMap and then

Object result = client.execute("ipb.fetchOnlineUsers",new Object[] {hMap});

It's work correctly